# Any idea how to redirect a page to login page based on its url when its refreshed

Tags: javascript, routes, redirect, page-refresh

I'm trying to redirect my page to login page when user tries to refresh the home screen, but if I add this code, the login page is redirecting to login page itself. Any idea how deal with this issue?

If I directly put window.location in index.html it works fine, but it works all the random url too (eg: /abcd, /asjda)

```
if(window.location.pathname == /home){
    window.location = '/login';
}
```

Comment: What's the error? You're passing /home as a variable, try putting it in single quote `'/home'`

Comment: yes i have tried this! login page is redirecting to login page itself when im trying to login

Comment: Are you using a framework? What web server are you using? You could force a redriect via the web server or the framework.

Comment: the thing is if i just put  window.location = '/login'; it works fine but if the same thing is put inside a if condition then its not even entering the url and redirecting back to login page. I want to take the user to login page when he refreshes the page

Comment: Oracle server And Angular JS frameout with restful web services

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
if(window.location.pathname === '/home'){

window.location = '/login';

}
```

Comment: yes i have tried this! login page is redirecting to login page itself when im trying to login